# only replace the width more than 300 using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

i wrote some php code that can change any

```
 width="any number"
```

with the string

```
 $width="300"
```

like this :

```
$width = 'width="300"'
$content = preg_replace( '/width="([0-9]*)"/' , $width , $content );
```

but in this code all the widths are change  , so i want it to replace only the width that is more than 300

so how can i modify my regular expression to handle this ?!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace('/width="([3-9][0-9]{2,}|[1-9][0-9]{3,})"/',$width,$content);
```